# React-Native TypeError: undefined is not an object . (Please explain what this error means)

Tags: android, react-native

I have Component class called Cameraa (the extra a in Camera is intentional) . 
After creating the component class, I am calling the component inside render() in App.js  but that throws the following error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluation '_reactNativeCamera.default.constants'). Please can someone explain me what am I doing wrong here.

Please note :
1. Developing Reat-Native for Android
2. Using react-native-camera library

Render Method From App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView,StyleSheet,ScrollView,TouchableOpacity,View,Text,Button, 
 StatusBar,FlatList} from 'react-native';


import email from 'react-native-email';
import Header from './components/Header.js';
import InputBar from './components/InputBar.js';
import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem.js';
import Cameraa from './components/Cameraa.js';

render()
 {


    return(

          <View style={styles.container}>




              <Header title="Todo App"/>
              <InputBar
                SendEmail={() => this.SendEmail()}
                addNewTodo={ () => this.addNewTodo()}
                textChange={todoInput =>
                this.setState({todoInput:todoInput})}
                todoInput={this.state.todoInput}

               />

               <Cameraa />

               <FlatList
                data= {this.state.todos}
                extraData={this.state}
                keyExtractor = {(item,index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem = { ({item,index}) =>{


                    return(
                        <TodoItem todoItem={item}
                        toggleDone={() =>this.toggleDone(item)}
                        sendEmail = {() => this.SendEmail(item)}
                         removeTodo = {() => this.removeTodo(item)}/>

                    )

                }}


               />




           </View>

    );

  }
```

Cameraa Class/Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    StatusBar,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
}from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';




let{height,width} = Dimensions.get('window');
let orientation = height > width ? 'Portrait' : 'Landscape';


class Cameraa extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            orientation
        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        Dimensions.addEventListener('change',this.handleOrientationChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this.handleOrientationChange)
    }

    handleOrientationChange = dimensions => {
        ({height,width} = dimensions.window);
        orientation= height > width ? 'Portrait' : 'Landscape';
        this.setState({orientation});
    };

    takePicture() {
        this.camera
            .capture()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.error('capture picture erro');
            });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" translucent/>

                <Cameraa
                     captureTarget = {Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk}
                     ref = {cam=>{
                         this.camera = cam;
                      }}
                        style={styles.cameraContainer}
                        aspect = {Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
                        orientation = "auto"
                >
                <View
                   style={this.state.orientation=== 'Portrait' ?
                   (styles.buttonContainerPortrait):(styles.buttonContainerLandscape)}
                >
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.takePicture()}
                    style={ this.state.orientation === 'Portrait' ? (styles.buttonPortrait)
                    :(styles.buttonContainerLandscape)}
                >
                    <Icon
                        name="close-circle"
                        style={{fontSize: 40, color:'white'}}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                </Cameraa>
             </View>

        );


    }
 }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        cameraContainer:{
            flex : 1
        },
        buttonContainerPortrait:{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)'
        },
        buttonContainerLandscape:{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom:0,
            top:0,
            right:0,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0.5)'
        },
        buttonPortrait:{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            padding: 5,
            marginHorizontal: 20
        },
        buttonContainerLandscape:{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            padding: 5,
            marginVertical: 20

        }


    });

    export default Cameraa;
```

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: Try this code `Camera.RNCamera.constants`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the official document of [`react-native-camera`](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera), All you need is to `import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'` module and then use the `<RNCamera/>` tag.

`Camera.constants` is causing error, i don't know why!

but recently I used `RNCamera` and it is working fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import styles from "./styles"; //external stylesheet for this page
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
export default class CameraComp extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            file:''
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <RNCamera
                    ref={ref => { this.camera = ref; }}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
                    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
                    androidCameraPermissionOptions={{ title: 'Permission to use camera', message: 'We need your permission to use your camera', buttonPositive: 'Ok', buttonNegative: 'Cancel',}}
                    androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{ title: 'Permission to use audio recording', message: 'We need your permission to use your audio', buttonPositive: 'Ok', buttonNegative: 'Cancel', }}
                    onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
                        console.log(barcodes);
                    }}
                />
                <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    takePicture = async() => {
        if (this.camera) {
            const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
            const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
            console.log(data.uri);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Karishma. For some reason when I  initially tried the code from the documentation of react-native-camera , it was throwing some errors. So I opted for a different example. But it is working now.

Comment: you're most welcome @user1462617 , as you have accepted my answer, can you upvote it too!

Answer (score 1):

You need an upper case `C` in `Constants`, i.e. `Camera.Constants.Type.back`.

This error is just telling you that `Camera.constants` doesn't exist, which it doesn't :)